# Is there another name for unrendered lard?

Tags: pork

I've always thought of lard as referring to just the rendered fat, but [the Wikipedia article on lard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lard) says that it can refer to either unrendered or rendered pork fat. Is there a name besides "unrendered lard" or "unrendered pig/pork fat" for the unrendered fat you make lard from?

Comment: So, we're wondering why we have suet ---> tallow but (unrendered) lard ---> (rendered) lard? I wonder if "pork suet" would be acceptable.

Comment: @Catija I'm sure the "why" is "languages are ugly". Anyway, "pork suet" doesn't seem to be ever used, so people will probably say "but technically" but it's mostly understandable, at least!

Comment: I would argue that the word should be "bacon", but English seems to have lost all of its meanings except for the cured fried breakfast strip.

Answer (score 1):

As the Wiki says, unrendered lard is "adipose tissue", also called "fatty tissue". It's often referred to by the specific piece of fatty tissue that it comes from: fatback, belly fat, leaf (from around the kidneys, the equivalent of beef suet).

It can also simply be called "fat". I see, for example, many articles to render [fat into lard](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fat%20into%20lard%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). That's more ambiguous than "fatty tissue", but it's much more colloquial and it's usually clear from context.